# Python HTTP POST to printer ulogin.cgi

Tags: python, http, authentication, printing

This script is supposed to connect to a printer (protected by HTTP Auth) and scrape its XML/HTML for information:

```
import requests

printer_url = "http://*redacted*/wcd/ulogin.cgi"

payload = {'username':'foo', 'password':'bar'}
session = requests.session()
r = requests.post(printer_url, data=payload}
print (r.text)
```

print(r.text) comes back blank and if I simply print(r) I can see that I'm getting a 500 error.

This is what the printer source looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="top.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<MFP>
<SelNo>Auto</SelNo>
<LangNo>En</LangNo>
<Service><Setting><AuthSetting><AuthMode><AuthType>None</AuthType><ListOn>false</ListOn>
<PublicUser>true</PublicUser>
<BoxAdmin>false</BoxAdmin>
</AuthMode><TrackMode><TrackType>None</TrackType></TrackMode></AuthSetting><MiddleServerSetting><ControlList><ArraySize>0</ArraySize></ControlList><Screen><Id>0</Id></Screen></MiddleServerSetting>
<PswcForm>HtmlFlash</PswcForm>
</Setting></Service><LangDummy>false</LangDummy><FuncVer>2</FuncVer>
</MFP>
```

I've tried pointing the URL to the page source "http://*redacted*/wcd/system.xml" where the CGI login button is actually located, but then I end up with a print(r.text) like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="autherror.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<MFP>
<Function>err</Function>
<LangNo>En</LangNo>
<Message>
<Item Code="Err_2">ReloginAttempt</Item>
</Message>
<Redirect>/wcd/index.html</Redirect>
<MsgVoid>false</MsgVoid></MFP>
```

Any ideas?  Your suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> connect to a printer (**protected by HTTP Auth**)

As far as I can tell, [HTTP authentication using request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) does not work by passing *username/password* as the payload.

Try something *like that* instead:

```
r = requests.post(printer_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
#                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#                              basic http auth. Depending your system,
#                              might require HTTPDigestAuth instead
print (r.text)
```